# Refreshing shopping card with JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, session, servlets

I have the following problem:

I am new to sessions in Java and JavaScript. I have one iframe for my shopping card, and one for the content of my webshop. I have articles that you can put in the shopping card as a part of a session.

How can make script that automatically sees that I put a new article to the shopping card in my shopping card iframe?

Comment: _shoping card_ or _shopping cart_?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will be attach the problem from other point of view. If I were you, I will create the shopping cart outside iframe (not use iframes) then you will need:

1. When user click on "add product to cart": You send product data to the server using javascript with ajax call.
2. The server will add the product to the session, database, .... (your storage) and return you and ajax status (ok or error). If all will be ok then you update your shopping cart on the browser.

I think this is a better approach.

**Using frames**
Anyway, if you want to use iframes, you should use postMessage html5 api to the iframe send a notification to parent page and then parent page will update the shopping cart on the browser. This method is not 100% available on some browsers like IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage